# Can't build the face recognition package

Tags: ros, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I got face recognition tutorial on ros wiki page:

[www.ros.org/wiki/face_recognition](http://www.ros.org/wiki/face_recognition)

but i can't build it. I tried to build the workspace using catkin_make and rosmake.
I use the command "catkin-make" in the face_recognition workaspace but it already contains a CMakeLists.txt so the command doesn't work. I also tried the "rosmake face_recognition" but I have this error "ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names." despite the fact that there is a "stack.xml" file in the folder.

Can somebody help me please?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146801/can%27t-build-the-face-recognition-package/) by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2014-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-01**:
Please edit your question to include more information, like the exact commands you are executing and the full output you are getting.

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-04-01**:
Sorry. I edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a rosbuild/rosmake package, so don't try to build it with catkin. The code hasn't been touched for the last two years it seems, so not sure if you can make it work easily.

Please make sure the stack is contained in your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable.

What does `env | grep -i ROS` output?

**Edit:**

To add your folder to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, you need to exectue `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/path/to/your/folder/containing/face/recognition:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` after the `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` command. You can either do this directly in the terminal, or add it to your `.bashrc` file.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-04-01**:
The output is :

ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/lib

CPATH=/opt/ros/hydro/include

PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

PWD=/opt/ros/hydro/lib/gscam

ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=

ROS_DISTRO=hydro

PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/lib/pkgconfig

CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro

ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros

OLDPWD=/opt/ros/hydro

The stack is not in my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. How can I add it?

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-04-01**:
Thank you, It works. But if I do a "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash", the path is cleaned so I have to do it again. Is there a way to change definitly the path?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-01**:
put both commands in your `.bashrc`

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-04-01**:
I add those lines to my '.bashrc' but it doesn't work.
"source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/procrob_functional-master:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH"

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-01**:
Have you opened a fresh terminal afterwards?

**Comment by [RosFaceNoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/14151/rosfacenoob/) on 2014-04-01**:
I just forgot to source the file before testing. It's fine now

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The catkin version of the face_recognition package has been released. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/face_recognition

---

Originally posted by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) with karma: 143 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1